# In Java, does (a == (a = b)) produce undefined behaviour?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I'm learning Java, and I have a question about the properties of the return value of the assignment operation. I know that Java returns the value of the variable after assignment in `x = y`, but when does this assignment occur: before or after an entire expression involving an assignment? Is it defined in Java, whether in the expression `a == (a = b)`, the value of the variable is getting modified *before* the comparison resulting in `true`, or if, the expression gives a value equivalent to `a == b` instead, assigning `a` with  `b` afterwards?

I know that `a == (a++)` is `true` while `a = (++a)` results in `false`- here it does indeed perform the unary increment later, even though a bracket is present.

```
int a = 2;
System.out.println(a == (a = 2*a+1));
System.out.println(a);
```

This did produce

```
false
5
```

as output, similar to the behavior of the unary increment. Is it just this way for my compiler, or is such behavior actually defined with the `=` operation?

Comment: While not recommended your code behaves in a well-defined way. `a == (a = 2*a+1)` first evaluates `a`  to 2, then computes 2 * 2 + 1 = 5 and assigns it to `a`, then compares 2 and 5 and finds they are not equal, so the final result will always be `false`, and `a` will always have the value 5 afterwards. It follows from left-to-right evaluation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is specified by [JLS 15.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1).

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

`==` is a binary operator, so `a` is always fully evaluated before *any part* of `a = 2 * a + 1` is evaluated.